# Recursive function in java?

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDollars(7);
    }

    public static void printDollars(int n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            printDollars(n - 1);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("$");
        }
    }
}
```

*How does the value of n get incremented after printDollars() function gets executed.*

Answer (score 0):

The value of n is actually decreased by one on every iteration.

When 7 enters the function for the first time, the logic checks whether the value is more than 1. Since 7 > 1, the value (7-1)=6 enters the next level of the recursive function. It happens several times (6 to 5, 5 to 4, etc), until the function reaches one.

One important thing to note, if you're just starting with recursion is that the dollar signs start to be printed when the code got to the point where n =1, since to reach that part of code, the machine has to get over all of the recursive calls. So the first '$' printed is actually one that comes from the call with n=1, then n=2, etc.

I suggest you try printing out n instead of '$', so that you get a clearer understanding of the way it works.

Comment: I can understand till the first '$' gets printed and after that how the value of n changes again?

Comment: The final value of n after the function is complete is unchanged. It is only decreased when passed into the "next" recursive call.

Comment: As you say the value is n=1 and 1<1 is false and it has exited out of for loop but still how it gets executing?

Comment: I would suggest that you read this article, it may explain things a little better than I could. https://hackernoon.com/algorithms-explained-recursion-54831247dd85